# Steque and the API implementations

Tags: java, data-structures, stack, queue

A steque is a stack-ended queue which is a data type that implements push, pop, and enqueue along with any other features that you wish to add to.

Note that I am implementing the steque with linked-list-based approach. Below is the code for my entire Steque class, the problem I have is whenever I try popping some element from the steque or to iterate through it I get the NullPointerException. The push() and enqueue() method seem to work just fine as I tested and I did thoroughly check my pop() and iterator() but can't seem to find any possible errors that might cause any NullPointerException. Any help on my code as how to resolve this will be greatly appreciated!

```
public class Steque<Item> implements Iterable<Item> {
    private int N;
    private Node first;
    private Node last;

    private class Node {
        private Item item;
        private Node next;
        private Node prev;
    }

    /**
     * create an empty steque
     */
    public Steque() {
        N = 0;
        first = null;
        last = null;
    }

    /**
     * pop (return) the first item on top of stack and modify first
     * accordingly to refer to next node.
     */
    public Item pop() {
        if (isEmpty()) throw new RuntimeException("Steque underflow");
        Item item = first.item;
        first = first.next;
        N--;
        return item;
    }

    /**
     * push item on top of the stack and modify the first pointer
     * to refer to the newly added item.
     */
    public void push(Item item) {
        Node oldfirst = first;
        Node first = new Node();
        first.item = item;
        first.next = oldfirst;
        if (oldfirst != null)
            oldfirst.prev = first;
        ++N;
    }

    /**
     * push item on bottom of the stack and reset the last pointer
     * to refer to the newly added item.
     */
    public void enqueue(Item item) {
        Node oldlast = last;
        Node last = new Node();
        last.item = item;
        last.prev = oldlast;
        if (oldlast != null)
            oldlast.next = last;
        ++N;
    }

    public Item peek() {
        if (isEmpty()) throw new RuntimeException("Steque underflow");
        return first.item;
    }

    public boolean isEmpty() {
        return N == 0;
    }

    public int size() {
        return N;
    }

    /**
     *  prints the steque from top to bottom

    private void printState() {
        System.out.println("Printing steque below: top --> bottom ");
        for (Node idx = this.first; idx!= null; idx = idx.next) {
            System.out.print(idx.item + " - ");
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
    */

    public String toString() {
        StringBuilder s = new StringBuilder();
        for (Item i : this) {
            s.append(i + " ");
        }
        return s.toString().trim();
    }

    public Iterator iterator() {
        return new LIFOIterator();
    }

    /**
     * iterator that implements hasNext(), next(), and remove().
     */
    private class LIFOIterator implements Iterator<Item>
    {   // support LIFO iteration
        private Node current = first;
        public boolean hasNext() { return current.next != null; }
        public void remove() {
            Node n = first;
            while (n.next.next != null) {
                n = n.next;
            }
            n.next = null;
            --N;
        }

        public Item next() {
            if (!hasNext()) 
                throw new NoSuchElementException();
            Item item = current.item;
            current = current.next;
            return item;
        }
    }

    /**
     * a simple test client
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Steque<String> steq = new Steque<String>();
        while (!StdIn.isEmpty()) {
            String item = StdIn.readString();
            if (!item.equals("-")) {
                //steq.push(item);
                steq.enqueue(item);
            }
            /*
            else if (!steq.isEmpty()) {
                System.out.print(steq.pop() + " ");
            }
            */
        }
        System.out.println("(" + steq.size() + " left on steque)");
        Iterator itr = steq.iterator();
        System.out.println("printing steque of strins below: ");
        while(itr.hasNext()) {
            System.out.print(itr.next() + " ");
        }
    }
}
```

Note: I am omitting all the import statements here but they are indeed included in my program so there is guaranteed to be no "undefined method" or "undeclared identifier" error in this code.

Comment: The Type `StdIn` is not a Standard Java type. This makes it hard to copy&paste your program and try to find the error.

Comment: Your `last` and `first` are not connected in any way. Try executing next code on a new steque: `steq.enqueue("asd"); steq.pop();`

Comment: @user3707125 last and first aren't supposed to be directly connected, they represent the top and bottom stack, if you will, in a stack.

Comment: @jah Yes I am aware of that. The StdIn was written and defined by some Princeton CS professors to "help" the students learn with minimal knowledge required in Java. You might want to use a Scanner instead if you are copying and pasting to test out the code.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is, that your `first` variable does not get filled when you only use the enqueue method.

Therefore the methods that access this field fire an NPE.

hasNext uses the field via `current`.

IMO the solution would be to catch the special for N == 0 in enqeue and fill the first element with the available element.

I tried

```
if(N==0)
  first = last
```

after the initialisation of last in enqeue and it works without NPE.

Comment: I see your point and I've made corresponding changes to my push() and enqueue() method however I am still getting NPE whenever I try calling these two methods, the changes I made in push() is that I added the else case that if the steque was originally empty then I'd set last = first. By the same token, in my enqueue() methond I added the else condition that if the steque was originally empty then I'd set first = last. Any advice on how this is still giving me NPE? Thanks very much :)

Comment: You don't really need an "else case" is. You just need an if-condition as shown above. Obviously after the initialisation of last. I checked for enqueue and it works without NPE. Maybe you should post the according snippets.

Comment: I have been testing my code and really could not figure out which one of the following methods I am getting wrong on, I am attaching pop(), 
push(), and enqueue() here in multiple comments as they don't fit in one single comment block:
`public Item pop() {`
    `if (isEmpty()) throw new RuntimeException("Steque underflow");`
        `Item item = first.item;`
        `first = first.next;`
        `N--;`
        `if (isEmpty()) { last = null; }`
        `return item;`
    `}`

Comment: Here is my push() method:
    public void push(Item item) {
        Node oldfirst = first;
        Node first = new Node();
        first.item = item;
        first.next = oldfirst;
        if (oldfirst != null) {
            oldfirst.prev = first;
        }
        else    // if only one element 
            last = first;
        ++N;
    }

Comment: Not sure as how to format snippet of code in comment even after I read the rules but here is my enqueue() method: <hr/> ---
---
public void enqueue(Item item) { 
        Node oldlast = last;
        Node last = new Node();
        last.item = item;
        last.prev = oldlast;
        if (oldlast != null) {
            oldlast.next = last;         
        }
        if (last.prev == null) 
            first = last;
        ++N;
    }